# Socket in C; infinite loop

Tags: c, sockets, infinite-loop

So I'm trying to write a program that can accept inputs on both the client and server. Right now, it's infinite looping when I move these lines in the while(1) loop outside of it, like I was told to do:

```
sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
```

I was told the reason why it's infinite looping is because the new socket is create and is now listen, while the old socket is still opened and listening. I've tried playing around with the closing of the old socket in both the client and server, but nothing is working.

Getting rid of the while loop obviously works, but then the socket closes after receiving the input. The goal of this is basically make a chat program. It both server and client doesn't have to be opened simultaneously (for an A+ it does lol), but as long as it can go back and forth sending and receiving input.

I've included the code for both client and server. Future thanks!

**server.c:**

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <unistd.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <sys/types.h>
    #include <sys/socket.h>
    #include <netinet/in.h>
    #include <netdb.h>
    #include <arpa/inet.h>
    #include <sys/wait.h>
    #include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3490"  // the port users will be connecting to

#define BACKLOG 10   // how many pending connections queue will hold

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    while(waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0);
}

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;  // listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr; // connector's address information
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE; // use my IP

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and bind to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,
                sizeof(int)) == -1) {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)  {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler; // reap all dead processes
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

sin_size = sizeof their_addr;
        new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);


    while(1) {  // main accept() loop


        if (new_fd == -1) {
            perror("accept");
            //continue;
        }

        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
            get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (!fork()) { // this is the child process
            close(sockfd); // child doesn't need the listener
printf("INFIITE LOOP");
//does this because it waiting for another process and it' stays opened and is listnening???
//Maybe look in the client for this
//also said that while loop isn't probably needed and to do 


//probably will need a recv
//input
//send
//recieve
char input[20];
char *pointer;
printf("Type in an input, q to quit: ");
scanf("%s", input);
pointer = input;  //will need to clean this up to be more effcient... later

//if (input[0] == 'q')
//{
//printf("Testing the if");
//close(new_fd);
//need to break out of loop
//}
            if (send(new_fd, pointer, 20, 0) == -1) //need to change the length to the actual length of the input... later.

//int send(int sockfd, const void *msg, int len, int flags);
//sockfd is the socket descriptor you want to send data to (whether it's the one returned by socket() or
//the one you got with accept().) msg is a pointer to the data you want to send, and len is the length of that
//data in bytes. Just set flags to 0. 


//accept needs to be outstide of while loop
//because after accepting, it blocks the socket?
//in the while loop is where all the sending and recieving happens
//after sending, do recieve

                perror("send");
            close(new_fd); 
            exit(0);
        }
        close(new_fd);  // parent doesn't need this
    }


    return 0;
}
```

**Client.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT "3490" // the port client will be connecting to 

#define MAXDATASIZE 100 // max number of bytes we can get at once 

// get sockaddr, IPv4 or IPv6:
void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET) {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;  
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p; 
/*
This is what is in the struct

struct addrinfo {
int ai_flags; // AI_PASSIVE, AI_CANONNAME, etc.
int ai_family; // AF_INET, AF_INET6, AF_UNSPEC
int ai_socktype; // SOCK_STREAM, SOCK_DGRAM
int ai_protocol; // use 0 for "any"
size_t ai_addrlen; // size of ai_addr in bytes
struct sockaddr *ai_addr; // struct sockaddr_in or _in6
char *ai_canonname; // full canonical hostname
struct addrinfo *ai_next; // linked list, next node
};

getaddrinfo() will return a pointer to this
*/
    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr,"usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    // loop through all the results and connect to the first we can
    for(p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype,
                p->ai_protocol)) == -1) {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: connect");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo); // all done with this structure

    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    printf("client: received '%s'\n",buf);

    close(sockfd); //as soon as client recieves message, it closes the socket. 
//probably needs a while loop in here in order to keep the socket open
//but what are the parameters for the while loop?

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: umm are you trying to accept multiple clients at once? because `accept()`, `send()` and `recv()` are blocking. You should be using `select()` to determine which file descriptors are ready because if you try to accept a connection when there is none, it will hang.

Comment: @1337holiday listen() is not a blocking function.

Comment: No, just 1 client. Basically a chat program with 2 people talking to each other.

Comment: @EJP my bad, your right

Comment: IMHO, writing network programs is not that easy.
You should learn a lot if you want to write good ones. I suggest you read my (the ?) network bible: Internetworking with TCP/IP from Douglas E. Comer.
Everything is very well explained and detailed. It's all you have to know about internet protocols and how to program with them. Sample clients and servers are provided within the books.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the problems is in the server.  I think there could be problems with your loop that's working through the information returned by `getaddrinfo()`, but the main processing loop also has problems.

You have:

```
new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size);
while(1)
{
    ...
```

This will only accept the first connection; you need to re-accept subsequent connections unless your server is a one-time server.  So, you should be using:

```
while ((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) >= 0)
{
    ...process new connection...
    close(new_fd);
}
```

Server programs typically don't have a user standing by to provide the response information.

---

This code seems to work.

#### server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <signal.h>

#define PORT "3490"

#define BACKLOG 10

void sigchld_handler(int s)
{
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
        ;
}

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(void)
{
    int sockfd, new_fd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    struct sockaddr_storage their_addr;
    socklen_t sin_size;
    struct sigaction sa;
    int yes=1;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
    int rv;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(NULL, PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
        {
            perror("server: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(int)) == -1)
        {
            perror("setsockopt");
            exit(1);
        }

        if (bind(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("server: bind");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "server: failed to bind\n");
        return 2;
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    if (listen(sockfd, BACKLOG) == -1)
    {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    sa.sa_handler = sigchld_handler;
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1)
    {
        perror("sigaction");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("server: waiting for connections...\n");

    sin_size = sizeof their_addr;

    while ((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size)) > 0)
    {
        inet_ntop(their_addr.ss_family,
                get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)&their_addr),
                s, sizeof s);
        printf("server: got connection from %s\n", s);

        if (fork() == 0)
        {
            close(sockfd);
            char input[] = "This is the response!";
            if (send(new_fd, input, strlen(input), 0) == -1)
                perror("send");
            close(new_fd);
            exit(0);
        }

        close(new_fd);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>

#include <arpa/inet.h>

#define PORT "3490"

#define MAXDATASIZE 100

void *get_in_addr(struct sockaddr *sa)
{
    if (sa->sa_family == AF_INET)
    {
        return &(((struct sockaddr_in*)sa)->sin_addr);
    }

    return &(((struct sockaddr_in6*)sa)->sin6_addr);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int sockfd, numbytes;
    char buf[MAXDATASIZE];
    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;

    int rv;
    char s[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "usage: client hostname\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof hints);
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    if ((rv = getaddrinfo(argv[1], PORT, &hints, &servinfo)) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "getaddrinfo: %s\n", gai_strerror(rv));
        return 1;
    }

    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next)
    {
        if ((sockfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol)) == -1)
        {
            perror("client: socket");
            continue;
        }

        if (connect(sockfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == -1)
        {
            close(sockfd);
            perror("client: connect (will try again)");
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "client: failed to connect\n");
        return 2;
    }

    inet_ntop(p->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)p->ai_addr),
            s, sizeof s);
    printf("client: connecting to %s\n", s);

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);

    if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    printf("client: received '%s'\n", buf);

    close(sockfd);

    return 0;
}
```

With the server run in the background, the client gets the 'This is the response!' message each time it is run.  The server works iteratively, processing multiple requests.  There is lots of cleanup work.  I'd need to go and study which errors that are possible from `accept()` warrant retrying the loop.  The code takes the conservative view that if one `accept()` fails, all subsequent ones will too and the best thing is to stop.  That's a design decision; you can change it if you wish.  I note that some possible errors, such as EBADF, would be permanent problems that no amount of retrying will resolve.  Others may represent transient errors.

Comment: This loop stops at the first error. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: @Jonathan, Moving the `new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size` as the while definitely worked, but why did you change the forking in the while loop?

Comment: There were too many comments; the 'infinite loop' comment was no longer accurate; the code in the loop was prompting and I'm blowed if I'm going to respond to prompts from a server process like that.  Personal prejudices, that's all.

Comment: Would you suggest taking out the `close(new_fd);` if I wanted to keep it prompting then?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm not sure what you're after.  The server's child process can do anything it likes — send as much or as little data as it likes, in as many operations as it likes — and when it is done, it should `close(new_fd)`.  At the moment, it doesn't read anything from the client process; it might be that you wanted to get some data from the client, modify it, and send the modified data back.  It all depends on what the program must do.  Eventually, though, the server's child process should terminate and that will close `new_fd`, but an explicit close is better practice.

Comment: Ah ok, so I need a receive() in the while loop before the `close(new_fd)`. The goal of this program is to get both the client and server to be able to send and receive data, just like a chat program. So in the client, do you think I should do a `send()` before the `recv()` or after?

Comment: I've not coded a chat program.  Your server would normally end up forking a UI, and the UI would read from the keyboard and the socket, displaying information as it becomes available.  The client code also needs to read from the keyboard and the socket.  In both cases, you're likely to need a `select()` statement or something similar to choose which channel has data ready; or you can use threads with one thread processing the keyboard data and the other processing the (incoming) socket data.  It gets more intricate.

Comment: Well, it's a simulation of chat program. For this, I don't have to have the sockets simultaneously be opened since it involves threads and I'm not quite there yet. I'm just doing basically a swing back and forth: server sends, client receives. Then client sends, server receives. 
From your comments, it sounds like most of the forking and listening of the sockets are done in the server code, right?

Comment: There'd only be forking in the server; yes.  The client code would iterate, and the server's child would iterate; both would look to see what's come from the socket and the local keyboard, ideally.  Don't forget, in a chat program, one person can send several messages before/while the other responds.  It isn't a strict alternation of messages.  Maybe strict alternation is OK for your purposes in the short term.